# Enthought canopy python -lpython2.7 not found

Tags: python, debian, enthought, pycuda

I am using Canopy enthought on a machine without su access.

Whenever i try to build any package dependent on python I get this error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

Any idea what's going wrong?

I am running Debian OS.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, is it a python package you want to build? maybe you have to activate one of the virtualenv builtin with Canopy so that the necessary libraries are available for the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what version of Canopy you're using, try to set your LIBRARY_PATH variable.

Example: export LIBRARY_PATH=~/Enthought/lib

Then try to build the package. This worked for me but I don't know the root cause as to why Canopy virtual environment isn't setting this variable.